# Show all message types which contain a given msg

Tags: ros, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to use rosmsg to query for all messages that contain another msg type?

For instance, I'd like to see all message types which contain a `sensor_msgs/Image`.  (querying services the same thing would also be useful)

Doing a rosmsg show on every message output by rosmsg and grepping it for the type is super slow, probably 10 minutes or more for all the messages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220975/show-all-message-types-which-contain-a-given-msg/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2015-11-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2015-11-15**:
I've never heard of a function/script for that, but the code for the auto completion for 'rosmsg show' should be able to create a list of msg definitions in which you could just grep. Sounds like a fun python finger exercise.

**Comment by [jeremya](https://answers.ros.org/users/23980/jeremya/) on 2015-11-15**:
Are you looking for "all" published topics that contain that message type? Or are you looking for messages that contain another message type (the message hierarchy)?

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2015-11-16**:
@jeremya messages types, I updated the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This can be a good start:

```
 grep -R --include \*.msg --include \*.srv "sensor_msgs/Image" $(echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH | sed 's/:/ /g')
```

Maybe a recursive call to grep is necessary, so you could find message types that use Image indirectly. But in my case this can be done manually, because I get just one result (and 2 comments):

```
/opt/ros/indigo/share/polled_camera/srv/GetPolledImage.srv:                      # against incoming sensor_msgs/Image header.
/opt/ros/indigo/share/stereo_msgs/msg/DisparityImage.msg:sensor_msgs/Image image
/opt/ros/indigo/share/theora_image_transport/msg/Packet.msg:Header header     # Original sensor_msgs/Image header
```

To exclude the comments:

```
 grep -R --include \*.msg --include \*.srv "^sensor_msgs/Image" $(echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH | sed 's/:/ /g')
```

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2015-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2015-11-21**:
Cool!  I've edited your answer to search the entire ROS_PACKAGE_PATH